# Find sum based on another column and use aggregate function in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I am working on SQL and I want to achieve this output in SQL using HIVE, here is the problem statement

I have columns Item, Cost and price.
The output I am expecting to have a following columns

1. 25% cost- Which is the 25% value of cost.
2. total_price- Its a sum of price values based on Item.
3. cumulative_price-Based on item it's a sum of cumulative price.
4. I want to flag those records which has cumulative_price>25%cost value

[image: Item: Cost: 25%Cost: price :total_price: cumulative_price: flag]

Answer (score 0):

this code will work on sql so try it.

```
with cte as 
(select *,(cost*0.25) as costx,
 sum(price) over (PARTITION BY item order by item) AS total_price, 
 sum(price) over (PARTITION BY item order by item,price) cumulative_price from dept)
select *,case when cumulative_price<costx then 0 else 1 end as flag from cte;
```

its work on me.